# stable homotopy groups of the projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, cw-complexes, stable-homotopy-theory

The projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is obtained by attaching a $2$-cell to $S^1$ via a degree $2$ map
$$
S^1\overset{[2]}{\longrightarrow}S^1\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^2. 
$$

**Question 1:**   the degree $2$ map
$$
[2]: \mathbb{R}P^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^2,
$$
in the stable category, is the composite
$$
\mathbb{R}P^2\overset{\text{pinch}}{\longrightarrow} S^2\overset{\eta}{\longrightarrow}S^1\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2.
$$
Why? What does this mean?

**Question 2:**
$$
S^1\overset{[2]}{\longrightarrow}S^1\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^2
$$
is a cofibre sequence and there is an associated  long exact sequence of stable homotopy groups. Why? What does this mean?

**Question 3:** apply the above to calculate the stable homotopy groups of $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Could you illustrate how to calculate?

Comment: Did you ask your professor?